# Import sheet1.xml from uncompressed XLSX

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xlsx

Im trying to import an XLSX file into my SQL DB (SQL2014) but we dont have the driver to import XLSX and asking IT to install it would cost our department a small fortune.

But we do have 7Zip installed on the SQL server, so i was thinking we could unzip the XLSX file, and then import the sheet1.xml that way..

Does anyone have any examples of parsing the sheet1.xml in SSMS using tSQL??

I've imported the xml using the below:

```
CREATE TABLE XMLTable (XMLDATA XML)

INSERT INTO XMLTable(XMLData)
SELECT CONVERT(XML,BulkColumn) as BulkColumn
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK, 'C:\sheel1.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;
```

Every xml parser ive tried just doesnt work or brings back blank data..

Comment: Is this a one-off? If so, maybe open the Excel file and save as CSV (or tab-delimited file) then import that? Or import into MS Access, then from MS Access you can export it to SQL Server using ODBC?

Comment: You can try using SSIS with a custom built source component. Basically you just need the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll (you might find it on your local drive if you have Office and its GAC utils installed). I do this in numerous cases where we have to import Excel files.

Comment: Is it worth implementing the import process in an SSIS package? There are plenty of quality free (and low cost) .NET Framework libraries out there that can import and export data from/to .xlsx files and so can be used from Script Blocks. Bonus: you don't have to understand the underlying file formats, including the fun and games with string lookups.